# LTspice: Change W and L values of a 3rd party library MOSFET

Tags: ltspice

[image]

[image]

I'm required to do some simulations with an NMOS and PMOS model. These models exist in the above library file.

I used the .include "file-path" command and changed the default MOSFET symbol value to the required model present in the above file.

However, I do not know how to change the W and L values.

Comment: 1) read the manual, this is not the LTspice helpdesk 2) in the schematic you place a MOSFET symbol, that symbol will have a W and an L property which is where you set the values you want.

Comment: 1)I referred to other sources before questioning here but couldn't find what I wanted 2)I placed the default symbol and changed the value but the option for W,L did not appear

Comment: I added " .M1(W=240n,L=180n) " into the spice directive and there is no error message.Is it correct? (M1 is the MOSFET name)

Comment: Please [edit] your post to copy the text into the question as text instead of as an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pressing ctrl during right click would open up a new dialog box, where we can enter the W,L values in the "value2" option.

Comment: You need the `NMOS4` and `PMOS4` symbols, otherwise you only get three pins, no bulk. Then you can `RClick` normally and insert W and L. All of this is in the manual.